# Latest Template Issue

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

Is there a problem with the latest 5.2.0 version of the template? I am selecting the following to generate the template.

1. Target Version: v3.x
2. Multi Page Web Application
3. Include login, register, user, role and tenant management pages

I generate the zip folder and download. Once the solution has built I run the Update-Database command and confirm that the database has been created.

The issue is when I run the Web.Mvc project. The page does not seem to render properly. It's like all the styles are missing at the login page. When I do try to login I get the following displayed in the browser:

{"result":null,"targetUrl":"/","success":true,"error":null,"unAuthorizedRequest":false,"__abp":true}

Can anyone else confirm if they are experiencing the same problems and advise if I have missed a step? I did the same thing earlier in the year with the 5.1.0 template and it worked.

Any advice, thoughts or confirmation is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution listed under GitHub Issues.

To resolve expand the Web.Mvc project, right-click on libman.json and select "Restore Client-Side Libraries".

The link to the issue and solution is: https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/5322

I'll leave this question/answer here should anyone else be having the same issue and not found the logged GitHub issue above.